# iOS Charts: Showing actual value with percentage inside PieChart?

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I'm currently using [Charts - by Daniel Gindi](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts), and following his demo, I've implemented a PieChart like so:

[image]

It was achieve using the following code:

```
func createPieChart(dataPoints: [String: Double])
{
    for index in 0..<sortedDates.count
    {
        let year = sortedDates[index]

        guard let costs = dataPoints[year] else {
            return
        }

        let dataEntry = PieChartDataEntry(value: costs, label: year)

        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    chartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")

    chartData = PieChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

    chartDataSet.sliceSpace = 2.0

    chartDataSet.yValuePosition = PieChartDataSet.ValuePosition.outsideSlice

    ...

    pieChartView.usePercentValuesEnabled = true
    pieChartView.drawSlicesUnderHoleEnabled = false
    pieChartView.holeRadiusPercent = 0.40
    pieChartView.transparentCircleRadiusPercent = 0.43
    pieChartView.drawHoleEnabled = true
    pieChartView.rotationAngle = 0.0
    pieChartView.rotationEnabled = true
    pieChartView.highlightPerTapEnabled = false

    let pieChartLegend = pieChartView.legend
    pieChartLegend.horizontalAlignment = Legend.HorizontalAlignment.right
    pieChartLegend.verticalAlignment = Legend.VerticalAlignment.top
    pieChartLegend.orientation = Legend.Orientation.vertical
    pieChartLegend.drawInside = false
    pieChartLegend.yOffset = 10.0

    pieChartView.legend.enabled = true

    pieChartView.data = chartData
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to show the actual `costs` value inside the pie slice, but also include the percentage outside the slice. The percentage is shown using `chartDataSet.yValuePosition = PieChartDataSet.ValuePosition.outsideSlice`.

Inspecting the code, I noticed that in `PieChartRenderer`, there is there function `open override func drawValues(context: CGContext)` and within it, the code calculates the percentage of each pie slice in `valueText`:

```
let valueText = formatter.stringForValue(
                    value,
                    entry: e,
                    dataSetIndex: i,
                    viewPortHandler: viewPortHandler)
```

Then using an `if` check, it draws the percentage inside or outside the slice, which in my case is outside:

```
else if drawYOutside
{
    ChartUtils.drawText(
                        context: context,
                        text: valueText,
                        point: CGPoint(x: 0, y: labelPoint.y + lineHeight / 2.0),
                        align: align,
                        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: valueFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: valueTextColor]
                        )
}
```

However, I can't find a way to actual include the `costs` value that is passed into `PieChartDataEntry(value: costs, label: year)`.

I was told to subclass the Pie Chart and override the methods I found but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

For example, the value of `costs` at each index in `dataPoints` is a double value of `100.0` for the label `2017` and `50.0` for the label `2016`. I would like to include both those values in the associated pie slice.

Can anyone experienced with this library assist me?

Thanks!

Comment: You need draw your value inside the chart or next to the % value?

Comment: inside the chart where the year is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that inherits from the `PieChartRenderer` and override the `drawValues` from the parent class like so:

```
public class CustomClass: PieChartRenderer
{
    override public func drawValues(context: CGContext)
    {
        // In this body, copy ALL code from parent class drawValues function

        ...
        let decimalFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        decimalFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        decimalFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        decimalFormatter.positivePrefix = "$"

        ...

        for i in 0 ..< dataSets.count
        {
            ...

            for j in 0 ..< dataSet.entryCount
            {
                ...

                guard let e = dataSet.entryForIndex(j) else { continue }
                let pe = e as? PieChartDataEntry

                // e.y = the actual value in the costs array, not the percentage
                let twoDecimalValue = NSDecimalNumber(value: e.y)
                let totalCost = decimalFormatter.string(from: twoDecimalValue)

                ...

                if drawXInside || drawYInside
                {
                    ...

                    if drawXInside && drawYInside
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                    else if drawXInside
                    {
                        if j < data.entryCount && pe?.label != nil
                        {
                            ChartUtils.drawText(
                                context: context,
                                text: pe!.label!,
                                point: CGPoint(x: x,
                                               y: y),
                                align: .center,
                                attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: yearValueFont,
                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: yearTextColor ?? percentageTextColor]
                            )

                            ChartUtils.drawText(
                                context: context,
                                text: totalCost!,
                                point: CGPoint(x: x,
                                               y: y + lineHeight),
                                align: .center,
                                attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: yearCostsValueFont,
                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: yearCostsTextColor]
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Within the `else if drawXInside`, the first **existing** `drawText` function draws the `label` value, in my case, the **year**. Add another `drawText` function and pass in the `totalCost` value, which represents the **actual** value in the array `costs.

Then within the `createPieChart` function:

```
func createPieChart(dataPoints: [String: Double])
{
    ...

    pieChartView.data = chartData

    let customClass = CustomClass(chart: pieChartView, 
                                  animator: pieChartView.chartAnimator,
                                  viewPortHandler: pieChartView.viewPortHandler)
    pieChartView.renderer = customRenderer   
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: could u provide sample how u created this chart @Pangu

Comment: the example is provided in the answer `Create a class that inherits from the PieChartRenderer and override the drawValues from the parent class like so:`

Comment: can you please provide sample code from using which drawValues you have created this PieChart ? @Pangu

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `yValuePosition` property to `insideSlice`

```
pieChartDataSet.yValuePosition = PieChartDataSet.ValuePosition.insideSlice
```

By default its inside but you specify as out side so its showing outside the chart.

**Edit :**

As per comment pls check below code which shows values not percentage in PieChart

```
func setPieChartData(lables: [String]!, values:[Double]!) {

        var valuesArray: [PieChartDataEntry] = []
        var colors: [UIColor] = []
        let valNSArray = values as NSArray

        valNSArray.enumerateObjects({ object, index, stop in
            //your code
            colors.append(self.getRandomColor())


            valuesArray.append(PieChartDataEntry(value: object as! Double, label: lables[index]))

        })

        let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: valuesArray, label: "Pie Data Chart")
        pieChartDataSet.colors = colors

        let piechartData = PieChartData(dataSets:[pieChartDataSet])
        pieChartDataSet.yValuePosition = PieChartDataSet.ValuePosition.insideSlice
        self.data = piechartData



}
```

[image]

Hope this will help.